# Is it possible to sort the filter of an update command on MongoDb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm migrating a Queue System based on MongDb/C# that I already had in other SQL Databases.

The SQL command that I would like to have something similar is:

```
UPDATE Orders
SET IsProcessig = true, WorkerName="Worker"
WHERE IsProcessing = false
ORDER BY ProcessingDate
```

In the orders table, I may have hundreds or thousands of records and to mark the one that will be processed by the worker, he flags the older Order with the worker's name.

In SQL Databases this query works fine, but I can't find a way to do a sorted-list-update in MongoDb.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SQL's `ORDER BY` use with `UPDATE`, especially when there is no `LIMIT`, nor `OFFSET`.  If the goal is to evenly distribute the docs between a fixed number of workers, and then update the docs with the required fields, [here's an example aggregation pipeline](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Z33ubDcU3gM) that uses `"$bucketAuto"` to group the docs to update based on `"ProcessingDate"`, get everything in the required format, and then `"$merge"` the updates into the collection.

Comment: Thanks  for the lead, 
Using the aggregation does the trick; now, I need to know how to write the same code in the C#. This is the example: https://mongoplayground.net/p/V4_Rw_rznma. I didn't find why to use the $bucketAuto or $unwind

Comment: I dreamed up a use case (probably different from what you want) of partitioning _the entire_ collection where `"isProcessing": false` to distinct workers - that's where my `"$bucketAuto"` came from.  The rest of my pipeline was just to assign imagined `"WorkerName"`s and `"$unwind"` everything so that the `"$merge"` would perform properly.

Comment: Regarding downvoting ... Users are concerned that the question is seeking a SQL translation service - that's frowned upon.  It's always good to show attempts with MongoDB with example documents and desired output.  Sometimes things "get lost in translation" but with specific input and desired output, working solutions can be provided.

Answer (score 0):

According with @rickhg12hs I use aggregation to be able to have the same behavior